# Obfuscating android jar throws unreferenced android.R$layout error

Tags: java, android, proguard

I have an Android library project, the jar of which I want to obfuscate before distribution. 
This library supports view and layouts, hence when I use Proguard to obfuscate the jar file it throws below warnings for all the classes that support UI creation and fails obfuscating. Below is the warning for one such file:

> Warning:com.event.android.eventui: can't find referenced class com.event.android.R$layout 
>   Warning:com.event.android.eventui: can't find referenced class com.event.android.R$id 
>   Warning:com.event.android.eventui: can't find referenced class com.event.android.R$string 
>   Warning:com.event.android.eventui: can't find referenced class com.event.android.R

I have used proguard GUI tool (\android-sdk\tools\proguard\bin).
The references and solutions I got for library obfuscation didn't have the ui angle, hence haven't found any solution yet.

Below is the proguard configuration file:

```
-outjars 'C:\Projects\event\eventpro.jar'
-injars 'C:\Projects\event\event.jar'

-libraryjars 'C:\android\android-sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar'
-libraryjars 'C:\android\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v4\android-support-v4.jar'

-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
-verbose


-keep class  public class **.R { *; }

-keepclassmembers class class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

# Keep - Applications. Keep all application classes, along with their 'main'
# methods.
-keepclasseswithmembers public class * {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}

# Keep - Library. Keep all public and protected classes, fields, and methods.
-keep public class * {
    public protected <fields>;
    public protected <methods>;
}

# Also keep - Enumerations. Keep the special static methods that are required in
# enumeration classes.
-keepclassmembers enum  * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

# Also keep - Serialization code. Keep all fields and methods that are used for
# serialization.
-keepclassmembers class * extends java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

# Keep names - Native method names. Keep all native class/method names.
-keepclasseswithmembers,allowshrinking class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# Keep names - _class method names. Keep all .class method names. This may be
# useful for libraries that will be obfuscated again with different obfuscators.
-keepclassmembers,allowshrinking class * {
    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String);
    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String,boolean);
}
```

Comment: I have one working obfuscating script, if yu want. But you need to do some changes in it.

Comment: @Pratik will it handle R class to. I believe if I remove the UI classes from the jar, the errors would go away.

Comment: R file will not be obfuscated, and no need for it also

Comment: Ok so how do I solve these warnings? Could you copy paste your script as answer. And why is it only complaining for R class interfaces?

Comment: that i dont knw, what is the problem in your script, but I have did it once and it was worked for me.

Comment: you need my script mili??

Comment: hey have you done with script???

Comment: @pratik, no luck so far. Could you please mail me at paraseth@gmail.com. Thanks!

Comment: ya I have did one mail, have you got it?

Comment: have you got it or not?

Comment: Didn;t got your reply, that's why I was think that you got it or not?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you update progaurd settings for you lib jar  file, you need make sure what is the root package name of the classes you are using from lib jar file.

As of now, I don't know what are the classes you using from your lib jar file (you can check this in your project import statements)

Example: I am using Twitter4J lib in my project and I know the roote package name of all the classes  (***twitter4j.*;***)
what I am importing into my project so added below two lines to my progaurd string config file and working fine.

```
-keep class twitter4j.** { *; }
-dontwarn twitter4j.**
```

Comment: had that been the problem it should have complained about the other android interfaces/classes as well. In this case it throws the warning only for R class.